# How to apply dense spacing between text fields

Tags: angular-material2

I have many text fields in a column with *normal spacing* as shown in [my Plunker sample](https://embed.plnkr.co/73T9rURSb71kLbGUKa0G/).

As stated in the [material guidelines on text fields](https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-layout):

> In forms with many or crowded fields, text fields may be made shorter.

How can I apply their definition of **dense spacing** between the text fields? Is there any built-in attribute in [Material](https://github.com/angular/material2) to use?

Comment: dense spacing in inputs are not supported yet, style it css for the mean time

Comment: Thanks @Vadamadafaka for letting me know. You may post this as an answer and I will accept it. I would be really thankful if you could show an example of the CSS needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in support in [material2](https://github.com/angular/material2/) as @Vadamadafaka commented. There is however an [open feature request](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4597) to add support for dense spacing.